# Interrupt thread if the task does not check for interrupted flag

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say we have simple task executing in thread, that does not check for interrupted flag, but we want to limit the time we want the task to run.

```
private class TimedTask{
     private final long limit;
     private final Runnable task;
     private final CustomVoidFunction shutDownCallback;
     private Thread t;
     private boolean wasInterrupted = false;
     private Throwable error;
     private String cause;

     public TimedTask(long limit, Runnable task, CustomVoidFunction shutDownCallback){
        this.limit = limit;
        this.task = task;
        this.shutDownCallback = shutDownCallback;
     }

     public void runTask(){
        t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
        t.join( limit );
        handleTimeout();
     }
         
     private void handleTimeout(){
        if (t.isAlive()) {
            try {
                // interrupt the thread
                t.interrupt();
                this.wasInterrupted = true;
                // invoke shutdown callback
                shutDownCallback.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.cause = "Error during calling shutDown hook in TimedTask!";
                this.error = e;
            }
        }
     }
}



TimeTask timedTask = new TimedTask(5000, this::computingTask, this::callback);

private void computingTask(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++){
         pritnFactorial(i);
    }
}

private void callback(){
    // log that the task was interrupted
}
```

`Thread$interrupt` does not interrupt/kill the thread, it merely sets interrupted flag of the thread. However in this case `computingTask` does not check for the interrupted flag, nor uses any library function that throw `InterruptedException` that checks it internally. Is there any way how to interrupt the computation in this case?

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no safe way to stop a non-cooperative thread.  There is `Thread.stop()` but it is fundamentally unsafe, deprecated and tagged for future removal.

Comment: @StephenC i see, do java apis such as ExecutorService also demands the tasks submited are cooperative threads?  From examples i have googled the tasks does not have to be checking interrupted execption at atll

Comment: The `ExecutorService` API does not require the tasks to check for interruption, but if a task doesn’t check for interruption, you can’t interrupt it. It’s that simple.

Comment: The only way to tell if a task is "cooperative" or not is to read the code, and understand what it does and how it does it. Maybe some day soon, an AI will be able to do that, but (A) we're not there yet, and (B) it always will be _impossible_ to do for some tasks. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)